# Append 1 pandas dataframe to another inside looping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I alter the value of a pandas dataframe "df_A" in every iteration of the for loop and keep appending it to dataframe "df_A_final".

```
 df_A_final = pd.DataFrame()
 for value in [1,2,3]:
        df_A['month'] = value
        df_A_final.append(df_A)
```

When I print df_A_final, it does not have all the values of df_A. Instead it has only 1 row. Just wondering what am I missing here. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: ``df_A_final = df_A_final.append(df_A)``, it is not in place like list.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_A['month'] = [1,2,3]
df_A_final = df_A.explode('month')
```